# GAE - Python - Query (filter) by Object property's property

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using GAE with python and I came across this problem, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
db.delete(db.Query(StudentVote).filter('topic.lecture = ', lecture))
```

and

```
db.delete(db.Query(StudentVote).filter('topic.lecture.course.owner = ', owner))
```

I try to delete a group of entities, each one have a topic property which has lecture property and so on.

> StudentVote->  topic->   lecture->    course->
>       owner

But the query doesn't work, is there any way to filter that way? a or what is the best practice acomplish this functionality?

Thanks advanced, Gal.

Comment: you can't do it this way. if you want to query on lecture you have to query on Lecture and not StudentVote and the same thing for Owner. but you cant 'traverse' like this on a query object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a common query, you'd want to put the owner as an indexed property in the StudentVote.  This would make your writes a bit more expensive, but it would let you query by owner.  Otherwise, if it's rare and performance is not a problem, you could manually query through the chain.

Comment: what is an indexed property? and how does it differ from a regular property?

Comment: Properties are indexed by default.  You can choose to have unindexed properties, which will reduce your write costs, but you can't search against unindexed properties.  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Unindexed_Properties